# why overflow when compare long long with int

Tags: c++, c

I'm writing a code like this

```
int reverse(int x) {
  long long res;

  ......

  if(x>0&&res>INT_MAX||x<0&&res>INT_MAX+1){
      return 0;
  }
  ......
}
```

It shows overflow,but when I add conversion to this it complies

```
int reverse(int x) {
  long long res;

  ......

  if(x>0&&res>(unsigned long long)INT_MAX||x<0&&res>(unsigned long long)INT_MAX+1){
      return 0;
  }
  ......
}
```

Can somebody please explain to me what is the problem?

Comment: Please provide a complete sample and inputs/expected output/actual output that demonstrates your problem. Also understand that C and C++ answers can easily differ

Comment: By definition, `INT_MAX` is the largest representable `int`.  How could adding one to it *not* overflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`INT_MAX+1` is evaluated as an integer addition of two `int`s. Since the resultant is not with the range of values that can be represented as an `int`, you see the overflow.

`(unsigned long long)INT_MAX+1` is evaluated as an integer addition of two `unsigned long long`s. Since both sides of the operator and the resultant are well within the range of values that can be represented as an `unsigned long long`, there is no overflow.

Comment: So (unsigned long long)INT_MAX+1 is equal to (unsigned long long)(INT_MAX+1) rather than ((unsigned long long)(INT_MAX)+1 right?

Comment: @Zongyang, no. evaluating `(INT_MAX+1)` causes integer overflow first. You have to cast one of the numbers first before the addition.

Comment: ok,I got it, my point is like if (unsigned long long)100+1 is equal to (unsigned long long)(100+1) rather than ((unsigned long long)(100))+1? I'm not quite clear on that.

Comment: The cast operator has higher precedence than the binary `+` operator. Hence, `(unsigned long long)100+1` is the same as `((unsigned long long)(100))+1`.

Answer (score 2):

```
INT_MAX + 1
```

In this sub-expression, the type of both operands of `+` are `int`, so the type of the result is `int`, causing integer overflow.

However, if you cast one operand to `unsigned long long`:

```
(unsigned long long)INT_MAX + 1
```

The type of the result if `unsigned long long`, thus no overflow, simple like that.

Comment: (unsigned long long)INT_MAX+1 实际上是 (unsigned long long)(INT_MAX+1) 而不是 ((unsigned long long)(INT_MAX)+1 是这样?

Answer (score -1):

What triggers the overflow is the expression

```
INT_MAX+1
```

Because INT_MAX is of type int (32 bit integer), INT_MAX+1 exceeds the maximum value of int.
Once you cast it to unsigned long long (64 bit integer),

```
(unsigned long long)INT_MAX
```

Is now well below the maximum value for its type, and

```
(unsigned long long)INT_MAX + 1
```

is valid

Comment: `int` is not necessarily 32 bits, and `unsigned long` is not necessarily 64 bits. Still, that doesn't matter.