# why does long long 2147483647 + 1 = -2147483648?

Tags: c++, c, undefined-behavior, integer-overflow, twos-complement

Why doesn't this code print same number? :

```
long long a, b;
a = 2147483647 + 1;
b = 2147483648;
printf("%lld\n", a);
printf("%lld\n", b);
```

I know that int variable's maximum number is 2147483647 because int variable is 4 byte.
But as I know, long long variable is 8 byte, but why does that code act like that?

Comment: range for int is actually [−32,767, +32,767], range for long int is [−2,147,483,647, +2,147,483,647].

Comment: @KerryCao sizeof(int) is hardware dependent, but on modern hardware it's usually 4 bytes.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438794/is-the-size-of-c-int-2-bytes-or-4-bytes

Comment: @KerryCao • until the recent 2s complement change to the standard.  (It's a moving target.  And very complicated.  Even with 2s complement, overflow of signed is undefined behavior.)

Comment: @Hoseong, Did you see some compile warnings?

Comment: Note that signed overflow was and still is Undefined Behavior in C++. Your compiler should warn you about this problem though. https://godbolt.org/z/krZBUa

Comment: [Relevant XKCD](https://xkcd.com/571/).

Comment: @KerryCao -- those are the **minimum** requirements; compilers are allowed to provide wider ranges, subject to the requirement that `long` is at least as wide as `int`, `int` is at least as wide as `short`, and `short` is at least as wide as `char`.

Comment: To get the actual range of a type, `#include <limits>` and look at `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` and `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`. Replace `int` with the integer type that you're actually interested in. (You can also use those two functions with floating-point types, but `std::numeric_limits<double>::min()` has a somewhat unintuitive definition.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why overflow when compare long long with int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702468/why-overflow-when-compare-long-long-with-int)

Comment: @Leos313, gcc gives `int.c:5:16: warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]`. But of course that doesn't tell _why_ it overflows, even though all the numbers fit in a `long long`.

Comment: How does such a question get so many upvotes?  Do people these days really not understand two's complement numbers?

Comment: The question should not be dual tagged, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374306/proposed-update-to-c-and-c-tag-usage-wikis

Comment: @ilkkachu `g++` under Linux it signs the position too :-) 
`a.cpp:7:16: warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]`
__`a = 2147483647 + 1;`__
__`~~~~~~~~~~~^~~`__

Comment: @TomServo The question is not about two's complement, but automatic datatype promotion (or lack thereof as in this case).

Comment: `a` is `long long int` but `2147483647` and `1` are not. Before being assigned to `a`, the expression `2147483647 + 1` is computed using the types of the values it uses and the type of both numbers is `int`.

Comment: This is a typical example of *operator precedence*. First, the numbers are interpreted as int and then, the + is performed. Finally, it's casted to a long. Different result would be `(long)2147483647 + 1`

Answer (score 131, accepted):

`2147483647 + 1` is evaluated as the sum of two `ints` and therefore overflows.

`2147483648` is too big to fit in an `int` and is therefore assumed by the compiler to be a `long` (or a `long long` in MSVC).  It therefore does not overflow.

To perform the summation as a `long long` use the appropriate constant suffix, i.e.

```
a = 2147483647LL + 1;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213422/discussion-on-answer-by-paul-sanders-why-does-long-long-2147483647-1-214748).

Answer (score 18):

## This signed integer overflow is undefined behaviour, like always in C/C++

[What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)

Unless you compile with [`gcc -fwrapv`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-fwrapv) or equivalent to make signed integer overflow well-defined as 2's complement wrap-around.  With `gcc -fwrapv` or any other implementation that defines integer overflow = wraparound, the wrapping that you happened to see in practice is well-defined and follows from other ISO C rules for types of integer literals and evaluating expressions.

`T var = expression` only implicitly converts the expression to type `T` *after* evaluating the expression according to standard rules.  Like `(T)(expression)`, not like `(int64_t)2147483647 + (int64_t)1`.

A compiler could have chosen to assume that this path of execution is never reached and emitted an illegal instruction or something.  Implementing 2's complement wraparound on overflow in constant expressions is just a choice that some/most compilers make.

---

The ISO C standard specifies that **a numeric literal has type `int` unless the value is too large to fit** (it can be [long or long long, or unsigned for hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41405578/what-are-integer-literal-type-and-how-they-are-stored)), or if a size override is used.   Then the usual integer promotion rules apply for binary operators like `+` and `*`, regardless of whether it's part of a compile-time constant expression or not.

This is a simple and consistent rule that's easy for compilers to implement, even in the early days of C when compilers had to run on limited machines.

Thus in ISO C/C++ `2147483647 + 1` is *undefined behaviour* on implementations with 32-bit `int`.  **Treating it as `int` (and thus wrapping the value to signed negative) follows naturally from the ISO C rules for what type the expression should have**, and from normal evaluation rules for the non-overflow case.  Current compilers don't choose to define the behaviour differently from that.

ISO C/C++ do leave it undefined, so an implementation could pick literally anything (including nasal demons) without violating the C/C++ standards.  In practice this behaviour (wrap + warn) is one of the less objectionable ones, and follows from treating signed integer overflow as wrapping, which is what often happens in practice at runtime.

Also, some compilers have options to actually *define* that behaviour officially for all cases, not just compile-time constant expressions. (`gcc -fwrapv`).

---

### Compilers do warn about this

**Good compilers will warn about many forms of UB when they're visible at compile time, including this.**  GCC and clang warn even without `-Wall`.  From [**the Godbolt compiler explorer**](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZugHZEDKqAhgDbYgCMALOQCse5dq3qhUAUgBMAIRmzyAZ2ydURAg2rZ6mAMLp2AVwC29ENPI7MAGQL1sAOVMAjbKRAB2cgAd0S4k16A2MzC19/QIY7B2cTNw9vFTUNBiYiVlIiENNzS2TsdSD0zKIYp1d3L2UMrJyw/Nqy%2Bwr4qs8ASmV0I1JULgByGQBme1RjHABqSWG9JSJCdAA6JBncSQAGAEFNrYA3dAJMSbp0CA7JT3ltydvJ9gZge8fJ1nJJlxnrrbvX6eGACKTaR8Ty8AAcwwAbLxPNM5JNuF9dr8XP8gSDYRDoRDkdtLgDdrsAPTE%2BxEV6kUiSACsskxYMhMLhCkRtMJw2%2BpPJlNI0lpsm4G2kvAAVEKReLhWKJbx2ejplckZ4ObJfurJqTJsBUKhieMxE8OA8AO6TDaTAIAL2wAy67BAAxpA3I5gGGxd6EdegUrKUPT62Hhw24LqIjo9HS6AGsQMMAJxLYaeYbQ8F8KGY7giR28F0mEC8DZLEHSTxQmnxmlg3hQ8EbGmuiOex0upQgDbkcPuu3kOCwFAYEw%2BAicChUCBDkdjkDAePDcg0UdEdztiAuZvkFz2TIAT0dofIQ5MOiIAHl6Ox9z3yDgTIbOJvCKRCho9th2zfsAAPQpGFcHi65KqJu7AEC4pB7gYOCbkQpAEAWAyhl0dCMCwHBcHwgjCKI4hoL6cgiOB7aQF06A%2BKk9CfgAtGe0iTNR36oG2qivkE2i6PU5jcJY1jlHECThH4ASUVxPCWMJUT0PxlQePkrFFGkTRiTxygKZRJRZDJbRyTUpQqY0pTaYJ0hdP6vT9Dw9qOs6TY3l6AzfuCULUTC2q6pMibDJMED4MQZDBtmkwGMOo7uIFHTBQRshhs2UbkEg2CsDgHjnDmAx5uQBbDLwSyeOCnjSDlGy8NINI0iGVZ2R65AOW2HZdnFfaIBAKA9EQPj/pQ1BTmFHjZtghAkP1i4MMwbCPlhJqQT4gHWU6LpujVDkjNwkwmsQSCTE5LluTqqCeUmsU9vFiXJVUaUOhl%2BYWI2S0tgM9Wdt2kYxnGXkpmmGZZulwyLZudWNSdzXwP2yBoOgoVjt1k6Q9OVR7KgPg%2BAA%2Bns3DxijIoo9%2BMKLsuq7UBuN7bvQe6AUekMnowF5Xk%2B2D3uIj43s%2BbHvp%2BNU/n%2BAFIUBjAgTeYEQVBWCDDVcEIXNo1oRNmH8EIli4RI0VES4JFpeRlE0XRDEAOrGixKTsRA1gqVYujGVU2aSaJhi5MINtBJbI0FIp9CadkdthNmrsaU0zvCPM%2Ble9xelaS0AlW2ZAaWdw822fdtWOrjvCTCYSiI5M6OJiKPl%2BcNgXvCF8OkMGplRXICjHa9CVJSl1BvaVSzzoVGzpvG3AY/G4KNldmUFrWJZgsM0g98yZVQtC1UPU9QORiDA4gO1nVEDDvUzrxQ1kMIqHjRhPD8NNrCzbz8f/fZjojPRG1EFtKdpxnB3ZyWmUvXaXRnfXl25jdFV5RPng%2BDDBpGWXgwDp5J0esoBqb94qxihMWTMUJJ7cB7smHu4IqpXT%2BhAwGsD5rSHPstVsc937kHfKQAIWheBAA):

```
  clang
<source>:5:20: warning: overflow in expression; result is -2147483648 with type 'int' [-Winteger-overflow]
    a = 2147483647 + 1;
                   ^
```

```
  gcc
<source>: In function 'void foo()':
<source>:5:20: warning: integer overflow in expression of type 'int' results in '-2147483648' [-Woverflow]
    5 |     a = 2147483647 + 1;
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

GCC has had this warning enabled by default since at least GCC4.1 in 2006 (oldest version on Godbolt), and clang since 3.3.

MSVC only warns *with* `-Wall`, which for MSVC is unusably verbose most of the time, e.g. `stdio.h` results in tons of warnings like `'vfwprintf': unreferenced inline function has been removed`. MSVC's warning for this looks like:

```
  MSVC -Wall
<source>(5): warning C4307: '+': signed integral constant overflow
```

---

[@HumanJHawkins asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61624859/why-does-long-long-2147483647-1-2147483648#comment109041845_61624886) why it was designed this way:

> To me, this question is asking, why doesn't the compiler also use the smallest data type that the result of a math operation will fit into? With integer literals, it would be possible to know at compile time that an overflow error was occurring. But the compiler does not bother to know this and handle it. Why is that?

"Doesn't bother to handle it" is a bit strong; compilers do detect the overflow and warn about it.  But they follow ISO C rules that say `int + int` has type `int`, and that the numeric literals each have type `int`.  Compilers merely choose on purpose to wrap instead of to widening and giving the expression a different type than you'd expect.  (Instead of bailing out entirely because of the UB.)

Wrapping is common when signed overflow happens at run-time, although in loops compilers do aggressively optimize `int i` / `array[i]` to [avoid redoing sign-extension every iteration](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html).

Widening would bring its own (smaller) set of pitfalls like `printf("%d %d\n", 2147483647 + 1, 2147483647);` having undefined behaviour (and failing in practice on 32-bit machines) because of a type mismatch with the format string.  If `2147483647 + 1` implicitly promoted to `long long`, you'd need a `%lld` format string.  (And it would break in practice because a 64-bit int is typically passed in two arg-passing slots on a 32-bit machine, so the 2nd `%d` would probably see the 2nd half of the first `long long`.)

To be fair, that's already a problem for `-2147483648`.  As an expression in C/C++ source it has type `long` or `long long`.  It's parsed as `2147483648` separately from the unary `-` operator, and `2147483648` doesn't fit in a 32-bit signed `int`.  Thus it has the next largest type that can represent the value.

However, any program affected by that widening would have had UB (and probably wrapping) without it, and it's more likely that widening will make code happen to work.  There's a design philosophy issue here: too many layers of "happens to work" and forgiving behaviour make it hard to understand exactly why something *does* work, and hard to verity that it will be portable to other implementations with other type widths.  Unlike "safe" languages like Java, C is very unsafe and has different implementation-defined things on different platforms, but many developers only have one implementation to test on.  (Especially before the internet and online continuous-integration testing.)

---

ISO C doesn't define the behaviour, so yes a compiler *could* define new behaviour as an extension without breaking compatibility with any UB-free programs.  But unless *every* compiler supported it, you couldn't use it in portable C programs.  I could imagine it as a GNU extension supported by gcc/clang/ICC at least.

Also, such an options would somewhat conflict with `-fwrapv` which does define the behaviour.  Overall I think it's unlikely to catch be adopted because there's convenient syntax to specifying the type of a literal (`0x7fffffffUL + 1` gives you an `unsigned long` which is guaranteed to be wide enough for that value as a 32-bit unsigned integer.)

But let's consider this as a choice for C in the first place, instead of the current design.

**One possible design would be to infer the type of a whole integer constant expression from its value, calculated with arbitrary precision**.  Why arbitrary precision instead of `long long` or `unsigned long long`?  Those might not be large enough for intermediate parts of the expression if the final value is small because of `/`, `>>`, `-`, or `&` operators.

Or a simpler design like the C preprocessor where constant integer expressions are evaluated at some fixed implementation-defined width like at least 64-bit.  (But then assign a type based on the final value, or based on the widest temporary value in an expression?)  But that has the obvious downside for early C on 16-bit machines that it makes compile-time expressions slower to evaluation than if the compiler can use the machine's native integer width internally for `int` expressions.

**Integer constant-expressions are already somewhat special in C, required to be evaluated at compile time in some contexts**, e.g. for `static int array[1024 * 1024 * 1024];` (where the multiplies will overflow on implementations with 16-bit int.)

Obviously we can't efficiently extend the promotion rule to non-constant expressions; if `(a*b)/c` might have to evaluate `a*b` as `long long` instead of `int` on a 32-bit machine, the division will require extended precision.  (For example x86's 64-bit / 32-bit => 32-bit division instruction faults on overflow of the quotient instead of silently truncating the result, so even assigning the result to an `int` wouldn't let the compiler optimize well for some cases.)

**Also, do we really want the behaviour / definedness of `a * b` to depend on whether `a` and `b` are `static const` or not?**  Having compile time evaluation rules match the rules for non-constant expressions seems good in general, even though it leaves these nasty pitfalls.  But again, this is something good compilers can warn about in constant expressions.

---

Other more common cases of this C gotcha are things like `1<<40` instead of `1ULL << 40` to define a bit flag, or writing 1T as `1024*1024*1024*1024`.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder, since the signed overflow is undefined, could the compiler decide to treat the result as a `long` instead? Or maybe that's what you meant with inferring the type from the values, but did mention "following ISO C rules that say the expression has type int", so I'm exactly sure if that would be allowed.

Comment: @ilkkachu: My answer does kind of contradict itself >.<.  The source contains UB so the ISO C standard has literally nothing to say about what should happen along that entire path of execution before and after the UB is encountered.  Yes, it would be fine for `2147483647 + 1` to evaluate to an int64_t as far as ISO C is concerned.  But what compilers actually do is apply the ISO C type rules and then wrap the integer value during compile-time evaluation.  ISO C doesn't require that (or anything else) in the overflow case.  Phrasing suggestions or edits welcome.

Comment: @ilkkachu: Updated with better phrasing.  Saying "ISO C *requires* it to be UB" implied all kinds of wrong ideas about what UB is.  e.g. that it's required to crash or required to warn, or whatever.  In fact it just means that you're in uncharted territory where the ISO C standard has nothing to say about the program.  Anything you choose to do is either just happens-to-work or implementation-defined behaviour.  (Implementations are 100% allowed to define any behaviour they want in cases where the standard doesn't define behaviour, e.g. like `gcc -fwrapv` or `-fno-strict-aliasing`.)

Comment: yep, thanks. That's pretty much what I thought it should when undefined. It was the part under @HumanJHawkins' question that got me. (that's where you had the "rules say it's int" written a bit strictly)

Comment: @ilkkachu: Ah right, I didn't look as much at that part of what I wrote earlier.  The ISO C rules do say that `int * int` is an `int`.  Current compilers are always following that rule.  So any proposal for this to work differently would override that rule for this case, which is one of the downsides to any proposed extension for current compilers.  Or even from a historical language-design perspective for how C could have been designed differently in the first place.  Not a good thing if `printf("%d %d\n", 2147483647 + 1, 2147483647);` fails because of a type mismatch with fmt string.

Comment: @ilkkachu: I had another look at the 2nd section of my answer and changed / expanded it some, including that phrasing you asked about.  I wasn't happy with my phrasing the first time I wrote it; I'd like to express the same thing in fewer words but IDK if that's possible.

Comment: oh, good point on the varargs types, that would be a rather annoying obstacle.

Comment: @ilkkachu: Also for C++ overload resolution I guess, like `foo( 1024 * 1024 * 1024 )` being `foo(long)` on systems with 16-bit int, instead of "just" being compile-time UB and a call to `foo(int)`.

Comment: It is worth noting that while C++20 defines two-complement singed integer, integer overflow is still UB.

Comment: Just an example of why relying on the signed integer overflow behaviour aka undefined behaviour is bad, see https://godbolt.org/z/scZLjI.

Comment: @dmeister: I'm not sure what that example was supposed to prove.  AFAICT, it will do exactly 1 iteration `0 <= 0`, adding `s += 0 % 77` = 0.  Then `1 <= 0` is false and the loop exits.  No UB.  If that's not what you meant to write, comment your code to describe the UB next time, please.

Comment: @PeterCordes sorry. you are right. My mistake. better example.: https://godbolt.org/z/haTK3P

Comment: @dmeister: There are many platforms and circumstances where it may be cheaper to perform some computations in arithmetically-correct fashion than with wraparound semantics (e.g. `(x*12345)/12345`) so I don't regard as astonishing optimizations which might cause computations to behave as though performed with an unspecified larger type.  Far more astonishing IMHO is the fact that in gcc, `unsigned mul_mod_65536(unsigned short x, unsigned short y) { return (x*y) & 0xFFFFu;}` will only work reliably if `x` doesn't exceed `2147483647/y.`.

Answer (score 6):

Nice question. As others said, numbers by default are `int`, so your operation for `a` acts on two `int`s and overflows. I tried to reproduce this, and extend a bit to cast the number into `long long` variable and then add the `1` to it, as the `c` example below:

```
$ cat test.c 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
  long long a, b, c;

  a = 2147483647 + 1;
  b = 2147483648;

  c = 2147483647;
  c = c + 1;

  printf("%lld\n", a);
  printf("%lld\n", b);
  printf("%lld\n", c);
}
```

The compiler does warn about overflow BTW, and normally you should compile production code with `-Werror -Wall` to avoid mishaps like this:

```
$ gcc -m64 test.c -o test
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:8:16: warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]
 a = 2147483647 + 1;
                ^
```

Finally, the test results are as expected (`int` overflow in first case, `long long int`'s in second and third):

```
$ ./test 
-2147483648
2147483648
2147483648
```

Another gcc version warns even further:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:8:16: warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]
 a = 2147483647 + 1;
                ^
test.c:9:1: warning: this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90
 b = 2147483648;
 ^
```

Note also that technically `int` and `long` and variations of that are architecture-dependent, so their bit length can vary. 
For predictably sized types you can be better off with `int64_t`, `uint32_t` and so on that are commonly defined in modern compilers and system headers, so whatever bitness your application is built for, the data types remain predictable. Note also the printing and scanning of such values is compounded by macros like `PRIu64` etc.

Comment: I tried to build the `-m32` and `-m16` versions. This failed on my Debian VM as it lacks proper headers to fulfill the compilation. On an OpenIndiana (OpenSolaris-next-of-kin) the 32-bit version built and worked same as 64-bit one, and a 16-bit one segfaulted right in `main()` so the results are inconclusive :) I hoped to illustrate it printing different integer values because `int` or `long long` definition could end up differently in those bitnesses.

Comment: x86 `gcc -m16` makes code that runs in 16-bit mode but still uses 32-bit operand-size (and the same ABI as 32-bit, like  `int` is still `int32_t`).  I don't think you can run the resulting binaries under GNU/Linux, even if you had libraries.  `gcc -m64` and `gcc -m32` also have identical sizes for `int` and `long long`, only disagreeing about the width of `long`.  Sometimes ISA details matter for UB, but not in this case.  The behaviour is effectively implementation-defined during evaluation of the integer constant expression, nothing weird left to happen at run time.

Comment: And BTW, you can get `gcc -m32` to work on Debian by [installing `gcc-multilib`](https://askubuntu.com/q/453681)

Answer (score -3):

Because range of int in C/C++ is `-2147483648` to `+2147483647`.

So when you add `1`, it overflows the max limit of `int`.

For better understanding, assume the whole range of `int` puts on a circle in proper order:

```
2147483647 + 1 == -2147483648

2147483647 + 2 == -2147483647
```

If you want to overcome this, try to use `long long` instead of `int`.

Comment: This is only guaranteed to work with `gcc -fwrapv` to define the behaviour of signed overflow.

Comment: This is an accurate description of 32-bit 2's complement signed wraparound, though, which is in practice what current C compilers do.  But it's not accurate to say the *range of int in C/C++ is ...* without any qualifiers.  C implementations for microcontrollers and DSPs with 16-bit `int` still widespread, and C only requires that the range be *at least* `-32767 .. 32767`, and that it's 2's complement, 1's complement, or sign/magnitude.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types