# Shouldn't 2147483648 + 2147483648 + 2147483648 be -2147483648?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm using MSVC 2019, and I'm testing something.

Thanks to lots of people, now I get this prints `0` :

```
long long a = 2147483648 + 2147483648;
printf("%lld\n", a);
```

So this time, I thought like 'what if I add 2147483648 for 3 times?', and I did.

I thought that the result must be `-2147483648`, because `2147483648 + 2147483648 + 2147483648` is equal to `0 + 2147483648`, and `0` and `2147483648` is `int` value, so it's gonna be `-2147483648`

In simple terms, I thought that the previous code is equal to this:

```
long long a = (int)2147483648;
printf("%lld\n", a);
```

But it didn't work. Here's the code what I wrote:

```
long long a = 2147483648 + 2147483648 + 2147483648;
printf("%lld\n", a);
```

The result is `2147483648`, and I don't know why.

Now I'm getting dizzy LOL

What did I do wrong?

p.s. the file's name is `tmp.c`

Comment: @user4581301 But when I add 4 times, like `2147483648 + 2147483648 + 2147483648 + 2147483648`, than it give me `0`, which is correct answer I think.

Comment: This depends on architecture. A `long long int` can be the same as an `int64_t` which can hold a max value of `9223372036854775807` just fine.. so adding `3 * max_int` will fit perfectly fine (`6442450944`).. https://ideone.com/VQq50M

Comment: @user4581301 no.. he's adding 64-bit integers.. `2147483645` is 32-bit and he is adding `2147483648`. If he did `long long int some_var = 3 * std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` then he's have int32 overflow. I changed my statement to say `can` instead of `is` for `A long long int is the same..` Sorry about that confusion.

Comment: VS-2019 shows for me (`2147483648` - undefined value and it's random what it shows): https://rextester.com/AMJ46137 but clang and gcc and icc all show `6442450944` (tested with https://godbolt.org/z/M7Zeu5).. I'd guess it's a msvc compiler bug but I don't know for sure.

Comment: @Brandon, we're both guilty of poorly worded comments. Hoseong Jeon's [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61624859/why-does-long-long-2147483627-1-2147483628) played with overflows and their expected result here followed the logic of the previous question's 32-bit math. As far as I can tell your interpretation and expected results are correct, so something funny is going on. I'm going to pull out  of this one and wait for clarification.

Comment: Note:  There is no signed integer  overflow here.

Answer (score 4):

In C, following C99 rules since `long long` did not come out until then:

`2147483648` is not a 32-bit `int`.  It is a 64-bit integer as `2147483648` is not in the `int32_t` positive range.

`-2147483648` is not a 32-bit `int`.  It is a 64-bit integer as `2147483648` is not in the `int32_t` positive range either, the `-` is applied after the constant type is formed.

The expected math output is the sum with 64-bit math.

---

```
int main(void) {
  long long a = 2147483648 + 2147483648;
  printf("%lld\n", a);
  a = 2147483648 + 2147483648 + 2147483648;
  printf("%lld\n", a);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
4294967296
6442450944
```

---

OP reports:

> Well, the output for me is 0 and 2147483648 when I copied your code.

OP is perhaps using a C89 compiler with `long long` extensions.  visual-studio-2019 is not fully C99 compliant. Example [Does Visual Studio 2017 fully support C99?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48615184/2410359).
In that case:

C89 uses different rules [e.g.](https://learn.microsoft.com/lv-lv/cpp/c-language/integer-types?view=vs-2019):
`2147483648` is not a 32-bit `int`.  It is a 32-bit `unsigned long`

`2147483648 + 2147483648` is unsigned overflow and well defined to sum to 0.

`2147483648 + 2147483648 + 2147483648`, as 32-bit `unsigned long` math is a 32-bit `unsigned long 2147483648`.

Assigning 32-bit `unsigned long 2147483648` to a `long long` is the same value, different type.

---

Moral of the story: Consider starting computation with the desired end type.

With the below code, the type on the left does **not** influence the addition on the right.  This is the same problem as [Why (not) write 1,000,000,000 as 1000*1000*1000?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40637622/2410359)

```
long long a = 2147483648 + 2147483648 + 2147483648;
```

Alternatives:

```
long long a = (long long) 2147483648 + 2147483648 + 2147483648;

long long a = 0LL + 2147483648 + 2147483648 + 2147483648;

long long a = 2147483648; 
a += 2147483648;
a += 2147483648;
```

Comment: Well, the output for me is `0` and `2147483648` when I copied your code.

Comment: OP is asking about MSVC, not standard C. See their previous question. However, they have not supplied code for this question and it is unclear as stated, so it should be closed until they fix this.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit my question. Can you tell me what I should add?

Comment: @HoseongJeon I think folks are looking for the original code appended to the question, you used to determine the sum.  Something like this answer, but what you coded - a minor coding difference to you may be important for others.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Ahh got it. I'll edit my question right now.

Comment: @HoseongJeon also include the name of the file. I'm not familiar enough with Visual Studio to know if it does this or not, but some IDEs decide which compiler or rules to use, C or C++, based on the file extension.

Comment: @HoseongJeon the best thing to do is make a small program that does nothing but expose the behaviour you are asking about. It doesn't seem to matter much here, but in many cases the real mistake turns out to be in a bit of the program the asker left out. What you want to give is a complete program anyone can compile, though in this case it looks like they'll also need a copy of visual studio 2019.